# ASP.NET: Logically dividing a user control's render

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I would like to have a user control where it's rendered HTML is logically divided up into sections. I would like an aspx page to dynamically load this user control that take each section and places them at specific points in the aspx page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible.  Make your usercontrol like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="section1">
content
</asp:Placeholder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="section2">
content
</asp:Placeholder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="section3">
content
</asp:Placeholder>
```

and the code behind add 3 properties like this:

```
public Control Section1
{
   get{return section1;}
}

public Control Section2
{
   get{return section2;}
}

public Control Section3
{
   get{return section3;}
}
```

then, in your aspx you would have 3 placeholders representing the 3 places where you want the sections of the user control to go.  Code in the aspx page_load method would look like this:

```
MyUsercontrol c = LoadControl("MyUsercontrol.ascx") as MyUsercontrol;
placeholder1.Controls.Add(c.Section1);
placeholder2.Controls.Add(c.Section2);
placeholder3.Controls.Add(c.Section3);
```

Comment: That is a very interesting approach

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sections that you want to render are not contiguous, no. Your options are to separate your control into separate controls for each section, or to create a class with methods/properties that return the code or control list for each section separately.